# How can I find the Size of some specified files?

Tags: file, size, sum

The command tries to sum up the sizes:

```
find . -iname "*.dmg" -exec du -sh '{}' \; 3&> /dev/null |
    awk '{print $1}' | summming_up_program???
```

Can you find a simpler solution?

**Ubuntu Solution. Thanks for the Awk-end to Ayman.**

```
find . -iname "*.dmg" -printf '%b\n' |
    awk 'BEGIN { s = 0 } {s += $1 } END { print "%dMB", s / 2^20 }'
```

Comment: The BEGIN { s = 0 } is unnecessary (though not wrong); awk variables are initialized to zero on creation anyway.

Comment: Also, note that files are stored on pages; you normally end up with more space being used than that calculation gives because a 1 byte file (often) occupies one page (of maybe 512 bytes).  The exact values vary - it was easier in the days of the 7th Edition Unix file system (though not trivial even then if you wanted to take account of indirect blocks referenced by the inode as well as the raw data blocks).

Comment: If You are satisfied with the answer (and You should be with Ayman's one) please mark one as accepted, thanks.

Comment: Jonathon Leffler: Very interesting. I had to open new question about your reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902618/historical-perspective-to-linux-filesystems

Comment: Reef: I am investigating Matthias Wandel's reply. I want to be 100% sure about things.

Comment: Reef: and your reply. I am experimenting to find out when your solution and Matthias' solution are better than Ayman's solution.

Comment: I just cannot understand the disparity between the results. Perhaps, the problem is that I do not fully understand Leffler's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -iname '*.dmg' -exec stat -f '%z' '{}' \; |
     awk 'BEGIN { s = 0 } {s += $1 } END { print s }'
```

[`stat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(Unix)) is used to obtain the size of a file. `awk` is used to sum all file sizes.

Edit:

A solution that does not fork `stat`:

```
find . -iname '*.dmg' -ls | 
     awk 'BEGIN { s = 0 } {s += $7 } END { print s }'
```

Comment: This forks stat N times where N is the number of files. Bad.

Comment: While this is true, `stat` retrieves the size from the file's inode. This should be much better than `wc` which scans the whole file. Also, this approach works for files in subdirectories.

Comment: `wc` doesn't scan the whole file, if You specify the filenames on the command line. See my answer for details. +1, I think the latter is the most efficient solution possible in bash.

Answer (score 1):

```
wc -c *.pyc | tail -n1 | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

Might be faster then cat'ing the files through the pipe. `wc -c` does not count the bytes, it retrieves the size from inode... or my hdd has a reading speed of 717 GB/s :-)

```
$ time wc -c very-big.pcap
5394513291 very-big.pcap
real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: This does not work for files in subdirectories like `find` does.

Comment: Also, `wc` scans the whole file to find its size. `stat` retrieves the size from the file's inode, which should be much faster.

Comment: I agree about not working for subdirectories, but wc does not literally count the bytes when given a list of files (it does count it, however, if You cat the file through the pipe). I have edited the answer to provide proof.

Comment: +1, thanks for testing. The source code of the `wc` implementation I looked at isn't smart enough to check the inode if you only request `-c`.

Comment: Also, I've edited my answer to add a solution that does not fork `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

cat *.dmg | wc -c

cat copies all the files to stdout, and wc counts the size of what was dumped.  Nothing gets written to disk.

Not as efficient, but even I can understand it :)

Comment: Can you explain why the results are so much different with the two commands: 1........ cat file | wc -c  2......... du file...........?

Comment: du measures usage on disk.
du would have been the obvious answer, but I assumed you wanted to know the total bytes in the files (that's what the complicated method does).

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced Ayman's non-forking command:

```
find . -iname '*.dmg' -ls 3&> /dev/null | 
      awk 'BEGIN { s = 0 } {s += $7 } END { print "%dGB", s / 2^30 }'
```

Thanks to Ayman for correcting my initial reply.

Comment: To append GB to the size, use: find . -iname '*.dmg' -ls | awk 'BEGIN { s = 0 } {s += $7 } END { printf "%dGB\n", s / 2^30 }'